# Getting Twitter Follower's names iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get twitter Follower in IOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495998/get-twitter-follower-in-ios-5)

Is there a direct API for just getting followers' names?

I was looking through and found out "friends/ids" will return ids? But, I just want screen_name?

Am I supposed to parse ids first and then send to "users/lookup" to get screen_name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be answered by sifting through **[this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids)** page in the Twitter development documentation.

Most important from that page is

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi
```

You *may* parse the numeric IDs, but the above will return to you the numeric IDs first, if I'm not at all mistaken.

*Additionally, to answer your question, "[can I convert the Twitter numeric ID to their screen name?]"

According to the description in the docs found [**here**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show):

> **GET users/show**
>
> Returns extended information of a given user, specified by ID or
>   screen name as per the required id parameter. The author's most recent
>   status will be returned inline.

So you can parse the returned data from this call as it suits your needs.

Comment: i was looking for direct api to get screen_name.

Comment: I edited my answer with additional information, possibly answering you.