# Get twitter Follower in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get followers name from Twitter using twitter.framework  in my iphone  application. I am using IOS 5.i want get that followers in to the array  and display in to my table.
Please give me guideline. Thanks

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a `TWRequest` for http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.format as documented on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-twrequest and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids respectively